# Concurrent login with identity server4

Tags: identityserver4

Want to logout from all other session(s) when user logs in other browser.
I am able to delete the PersistedGrants but cookies are still present.
When user refreshes the page a new access_token is generated due to refresh_token.
So basically we want only one concurrent session of user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Delete the `refresh_token` from the persisted grants table as well?

Comment: I managed this by caching session in redis(ITicketStore), the key being userId+sessionId if user logs in in new session then delete all the keys for the userId from redis and also clear persisted grant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default IdSrv persists user session in a cookie. You can change that by implementing IUserSession and registering in DI. Doing so you get access to logged in clients within one session. Having that knowledge, you can register your custom middleware with the check: *when authenticated, i.e. has auth cookie, and **no** other session for the same user id then ok, else handle the collision: the one who logged in earlier logs out*. Just an idea, but should work. [See my customization](https://github.com/dfrunet/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Extensions/ExtendedUserSession.cs) of the DefaultUserSession - backing it to Redis, used for another purpose, but should be enough to demonstrate the approach.

Comment: I managed this by caching session in redis, the key being userId+sessionId if user logs in in new session then delete all the keys for the userId from redis and also clear persisted grant